# Replacing Arduino with simpler components

Tags: arduino, circuit-design

I have been working on a simple project and would like to refine it further. Basically, a PIR sensor is used to check for movement. It then waits until the detected movement stops,  starts a count-down of a predefined length and once this count-down reaches zero, it activates a light.

In my current setup I'm using an Arduino, but I have the feeling that there are other approaches with more inexpensive hardware. Ideally, I would like to optimize for both power consumption and cost. What types of components would be advisable for a project like this?

Comment: One option is to design a custom PCB with the cheapest components you want and redesign the software for the cheapest and least consuming MCU you can find. Or do you still want to use Arduino compatible hardware and software libraries? You don't really define what you want to do and within which limits.

Comment: You could probably use a monostable multivibrator IC. If that's cheaper, well who can tell these days. Looking at component costs only, microcontrollers are no longer necessarily more expensive than standard IC. On the other hand, the whole semiconductor industry has currently collapsed underneath its own incompetence, so all MCUs are quite expensive at the moment. Looking at development costs though, MCU programs don't write themselves for free. Wheras using standard 74HC logic etc might require more effort from the hardware designer than when using a MCU.

Comment: @Justme for me it's mostly a learning experience. I come from a programming background and have very limited knowledge of (even basic) electronics. Given my background, Arduino is a very safe option for me. However, I want to move towards more fundamental electronics. I am not bound to the Arduino in any way. If possible, I want to replicate my current results, but with simpler (non-MCU) building blocks. My assumption was that these would also be cheaper & more power efficient than the Arduino, but this might be very wrong.

Comment: @Lundin, thank you, I'll look into that! 555 timers (which you might be referring to?) are about 30 times cheaper for me :)

Comment: Kind of depends on what you need it to drive. Something like MC14538 can source/sink up to 10mA, but if your LED needs more current than that you'll need an extra BJT/MOSFET.

Comment: The cheapest Arduino costs a few dollars.  An appropriate microcontroller can be programmed so that you need support logic and power. Lower cost is certainly possible BUT the flexibility you lose is immense. If you are building one off or low volume then a processor solution may well be a very good one.

Comment: **August 18th:** This question has a high chance of being reopened if closed IF no reasons for close votes are not given. Doing so is never obligatory, but is liable to usually be a very good idea.

Comment: **August 26th**: The close vote reasons given are rubbish. This is in large part the fault of the site BUT given that the reasons are poor, it would be reasonable for some reasons for close-voting to be given.